# Positive integers have the form $a^2+b^2+c^2+2^d$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, conjectures, sums-of-squares

For any positive integer $n$ there seems to be non-negative integers $a,b,c,d$ such that

$$n=a^2+b^2+c^2+2^d.$$

Due to Legendre's three-square theorem a natural number can be represented as the sum of three squares of integers

$$m=a^2+b^2+c^2$$

if and only if $m$ is not of the form $m=4^a(8b+7)$, for integers $a$ and $b$. If the conjecture is true, then for all $n\geq 1$ it must exist a $k$ such that $n-2^k$ is not of the form $m=4^a(8b+7)$.

I want help to prove the conjecture or to find a counter-example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We claim that $n$ can be written as $a^2+b^2+c^2+x$ where $x\in\{1,2,4\}$. Indeed, otherwise, we must have that

$$n-1,n-2,n-4$$

are each of the form $4^a(8b+7)$. However, all such numbers are either $\equiv 0$ or $\equiv 3\bmod 4$, while $n-1,n-2,n-4$ are each members of different residues $\bmod 4$. So, it only remains to prove this in the case for which these are not all positive integers, namely $n\leq 4$. We have

$$0^2+0^2+0^2+2^0=1$$

$$0^2+0^2+0^2+2^1=2$$

$$0^2+0^2+1^2+2^1=3$$

$$0^2+0^2+0^2+2^2=4.$$

Comment: `or ≡3mod4, while n−1,n−2,n−4 are each members of different residues`: How do you know that $a^2+b^2+c^2$ can only be $1$ or $2$ ?

Comment: A nice theorem!

Comment: U talking to me?

Comment: @Diger $a^2+b^2+c^2$ can be equivalent to $0$ or $3\bmod 4$, but using the result that Lehs states in the question, we know the only numbers **not** representable in that form are those of the form $4^x(8y+7)$ for some nonnegative integers $x,y$. All such numbers are either equivalent to $0$ or $3\bmod 4$, so $a^2+b^2+c^2$ reaches **all** numbers equivalent to $1$ or $2\bmod 4$. At least one of $(n-1,n-2,n-4)$ is of this form.

Comment: `At least one of (n−1,n−2,n−4) is of this form` ?? I thought all?

Comment: @Diger At least one of $(n-1,n-2,n-4)$ is equivalent to $1$ or $2\bmod 4$, which is sufficient (write that number as $a^2+b^2+c^2$ and add either one of $1,2,4$). If we take $n\equiv 0\bmod 4$, we have $n-4\equiv 0\bmod 4$ and $n-1\equiv 3\bmod 4$, so it is possible that only one of them can be written as the sum of three squares.

Comment: Ok, so if $n$ can not be written as $a^2+b^2+c^2+x$ then it is clear that $n-x$ is of the form $4^a(8^b+7)$. However if e.g. $x=1$ you claim that additionally $n-2$ and $n-4$ are of this form. How do you see that?

Comment: @Diger The form $4^a(8b+7)$ is difficult to deal with, so I use the weaker condition that if $n$ cannot be written as $a^2+b^2+c^2+x$ then $n-x$ is of the form $4k$ or $4k+3$ (as all numbers of the form $4^a(8b+7)$ are either $4k$ or $4k+3$ for some integer $k$). Since $n-1,n-2,n-4$ all take different residues $\bmod 4$, one of them must be $4k+1$ or $4k+2$, and it is thus $a^2+b^2+c^2$ for some $a,b,c$.

Comment: Ok I get it. But could you then not also simply argue: If $n \equiv 1,2 \mod 4$ then it can be written as $a^2+b^2+c^2$. Thus $n-4 + \underbrace{4}_x$ can be written by these 3 squares and a power of $2$. Also if $n \equiv 3,0 \mod 4$ then $n-2 + \underbrace{2}_x$ and $n-2$ again is those three squares for remainder $1$ or $2$. So you actually only need $x\in \{2,4\}$.

Comment: @Diger Yes, that works - my argument was just what I came up with first. There are likely many similar ways to attack this problem.